# Recommended way to have OAPH-backed Output Property work like a normal property?

Tags: reactiveui

Problem: I have a property set up using the OAPH as suggested by your docs. But because the OAPH observes using the UI thread, depending on which which thread a property is referenced in, the property [may not behave like a normal property](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/785) (i.e. a getter function). It doesn't immediately provide an updated value based on the getter function code you provide. Instead it returns a cached value (if you're on the correct thread this isn't a problem).  I assume this benefits UI responsiveness in some way.

```
class Rectangle
{
    private int _height;
    public int Height { get => _height; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _height, value); }

    private int _width;
    public int Width { get => _width; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _width, value); }

    readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isSquare;
    public bool IsSquare => _isSquare.Value;

    public Rectangle
    {
        /**/
        _isSquare = this.WhenAnyValue(
                        This => This.Width,
                        This => This.Height,
                        (h,w) => (h == w))
                        .ToProperty(this, This => This.IsSquare);
        /**/
    }

    void SetHeightAndWidthToTwo()
    {
        Height = 2;
        Width = 2;
        // Width and Height have been updated and PropertyChanged
        // notifications have been raised by each. But if we're not
        // in the UI thread, IsSquare might not update immediately,
        // so this fails.
        Debug.Assert(IsSquare);
    }
}
```

However, I'd like for the properties in my VM code to behave like normal properties. What is the suggested way to do this? I can think of three options here.

Option 1: Use ImmediateScheduler when making OAPH

```
// In ctor:
_isSquare = this.WhenAnyValue(
    This => This.Width,
    This => This.Height,
    (h,w) => (h == w))
    .ToProperty(this, This => This.IsSquare, scheduler:ImmediateScheduler.Instance);
```

Option 2: Make a "normal" property as well as an output property. This causes a simple computation to be performed twice, but I imagine that's n.b.d. compared to the UI-related computational waste that ReactiveUI's scheduling was chosen to avoid.

```
public bool IsSquare => (Height == Width);
readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isSquareOutput;
public bool IsSquareOutput => _isSquareOutput.Value;

// in ctor:
_isSquareOutput = this.WhenAnyValue(
    This => This.Width,
    This => This.Height,
    (h,w) => this.IsSquare)
    .ToProperty(this, This => This.IsSquareOutput);
```

Option 3: Make custom OAPH, which allows me to wait for the chosen Scheduler to update the Value field. I'm no Rxpert, so if this is a good idea, I'd like to know how to do it.

```
readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isSquare;
public bool IsSquare => _isSquare.WaitForValue(); // ??
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "behave like normal properties?" You can reference the property values e.g. IsSquare in code just like you would any other property.

Comment: It doesn't immediately provide an updated value based on the function you provide. Instead it returns a cached value (if you're on the correct thread this isn't a problem). [Here's another example of what I mean](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/785). I added link to clarify.